# How to parse stream of logs aggregated from multiple files with logstash?

Tags: gitlab, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I have logs from GitLab installed on Kubernetes. Amongst other pods, there is Sidekiq which has a very peculiar structure of logs - it gathers multiple files that all then go into the stdout (see example at the end or [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html)). I want to gather all these logs by Filebeat, send them to Logstash and process them in a sane way (parse JSONs, get important data from line logs, etc. Also, I would like to add info about the original file) and send the output to elasticsearch.

However, I am struggling with how to do that - as a newbie regarding Logstash I am not sure how it works under the hood - and so far, I was able to come up only with grok that matches line with the file name.

From one perspective it should be relatively easy - I just need to use some sort of a state to mark which file is being processed in the log stream but in the first place I am not sure if Filebeat somehow passes information about the stream to Logstash (important to distinguish from which pod logs came) and secondly whether Logstash allows this state-based processing of log stream.

Is it possible to parse these logs and add the original filename as a field this state-based way? Could you possibly point me in the right direction?

```
    filter {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "\*\*\* %{PATH:file} \*\*\*"}
        }

        if [file] == "/var/log/gitlab/production_json.log" {
            json {
                match => { ... }
            }
        }
        else if [file] == "/var/log/gitlab/application_json.log" {
             grok {
                match => { ... }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please notice that even for each file, there might be multiple types of logs (/var/log/gitlab/sidekiq_exporter.log)

```
*** /var/log/gitlab/application.log ***
2020-11-18T10:08:28.568Z: Cannot obtain an exclusive lease for Namespace::AggregationSchedule. There must be another instance already in execution.

*** /var/log/gitlab/application_json.log ***
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2020-11-18T10:08:28.568Z","correlation_id":"BsVuSTdkM45","message":"Cannot obtain an exclusive lease for Namespace::AggregationSchedule. There must be another instance already in execution."}

*** /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq_exporter.log ***
[2020-11-18T10:08:32.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:08:32 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:08:42.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:08:42 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:08:43.771+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:08:43 UTC] "GET /liveness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:08:52.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:08:52 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:09:02.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:09:02 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:09:12.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:09:12 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:09:22.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:09:22 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:09:32.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:09:32 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:09:42.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:09:42 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:09:43.771+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:09:43 UTC] "GET /liveness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:09:52.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:09:52 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:10:02.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:10:02 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:10:12.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:10:12 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
2020-11-18T10:10:15.783Z 10 TID-oslmgxbxm PagesDomainSslRenewalCronWorker JID-e4891c8d6d57d73f401da697 INFO: start
2020-11-18T10:10:15.807Z 10 TID-oslmgxbxm PagesDomainSslRenewalCronWorker JID-e4891c8d6d57d73f401da697 INFO: done: 0.024 sec
[2020-11-18T10:10:22.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:10:22 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:10:32.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:10:32 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:10:42.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:10:42 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:10:43.771+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:10:43 UTC] "GET /liveness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"

*** /var/log/gitlab/application_json.log ***
{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2020-11-18T10:49:11.565Z","correlation_id":"H9wDObekY74","message":"Cannot obtain an exclusive lease for Ci::PipelineProcessing::AtomicProcessingService. There must be another instance already in execution."}

*** /var/log/gitlab/application.log ***
2020-11-18T10:49:11.564Z: Cannot obtain an exclusive lease for Ci::PipelineProcessing::AtomicProcessingService. There must be another instance already in execution.
2020-11-18T10:49:11.828Z 10 TID-gn2cjsz0a ProjectServiceWorker JID-ccb9b5b0f74ced684e15af75 INFO: done: 0.275 sec
2020-11-18T10:49:11.835Z 10 TID-gn2dwudy2 Namespaces::ScheduleAggregationWorker JID-7db9fe9200701bbc7dc7360c INFO: start
2020-11-18T10:49:11.844Z 10 TID-gn2dwudy2 Namespaces::ScheduleAggregationWorker JID-7db9fe9200701bbc7dc7360c INFO: done: 0.009 sec
2020-11-18T10:49:11.888Z 10 TID-oslmgxbxm ArchiveTraceWorker JID-999cc768143b644d051cfe82 INFO: done: 0.21 sec

*** /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq_exporter.log ***
[2020-11-18T10:49:12.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:49:12 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:49:22.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:49:22 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:49:32.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:49:32 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
[2020-11-18T10:49:42.076+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:49:42 UTC] "GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
2020-11-18T10:49:43.216Z 10 TID-gn2cjsz0a Namespaces::RootStatisticsWorker JID-c277b38f3daa09648934d99f INFO: start
2020-11-18T10:49:43.243Z 10 TID-gn2cjsz0a Namespaces::RootStatisticsWorker JID-c277b38f3daa09648934d99f INFO: done: 0.027 sec
[2020-11-18T10:49:43.771+0000] 10.103.149.75 - - [18/Nov/2020:10:49:43 UTC] "GET /liveness HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "kube-probe/1.17+"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give all the logs path in `filebeat.yml` for filebeat to read the logs and send it to logstash.

Example `filebeat.yml` for gitlab:

```yaml
###################### Filebeat Configuration Example #########################

#=========================== Filebeat inputs =============================

filebeat.inputs:

    -
      paths:
        - /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/application_json.log
      fields:
        - type: gitlab-application-json
      fields_under_root: true
      encoding: utf-8
    -
      paths:
        - /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq_exporter.log
      fields:
        - type: gitlab-sidekiq-exporter
      fields_under_root: true
      encoding: utf-8
    -
      paths:
        - /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/api_json.log
      fields:
        - type: gitlab-api-json
      fields_under_root: true
      encoding: utf-8

    -
      paths:
        - /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/application.log
      fields:
        - type: gitlab-application
      fields_under_root: true
      encoding: utf-8



#============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["10.127.55.155:5066"]

#================================ Processors =====================================

# Configure processors to enhance or manipulate events generated by the beat.

processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

Now, in logstash, you can create different grok pattern to filter these logs.

Here is a sample `logstash.yml`,

```
input {

 beats {
        port => "5066"
    }
  }
  
filter {

      if [type] == "gitlab-sidekiq-exporter" {
      
            grok {
               match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] %{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[(?<timestamp>%{MONTHDAY}/%{MONTH}/%{YEAR}\:%{TIME}) %{TZ:timezone}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent}" }
               overwrite => [ "message" ]
           }
    }
    
filter {
      mutate {
          remove_tag => [
              "_grokparsefailure"
          ]
      }
  }

output {
 
     #filtered logs are getting indexed in elasticsearch
     
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["10.127.55.155:9200"]
                user => elastic
                password => elastic
                action => "index"
                index => "gitlab"
        }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }  #filtered logs can be seen as console output as well, you can comment this out as well, this is for debugging purpose only
 }
```

> Note: The beat input port in `logstash.yml` should be same, as given in **output.logstash** in `filebeat.yml`

You can append the `logstash.yml` for filtering out **application_json.log** and **application.log** similar to that of **sidekiq_exporter.log**

For creating and validating grok pattern to filter the logs, you can use online [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

Here, I have used the Grok Debugger to create a pattern for filtering **sidekiq_exporter.log**

**Pattern:** `%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent}`

[image]

Comment: I see, the very positive thing is those Filebeat marks. That will be definitely useful. Unfortunately, this approach circumvents the problem a little bit. We have installed GitLab as a helm chart and it does not exactly support logging per file as you suppose. I mean it does inside the pod, but the logs are then collected and aggregated to stdout of the container and original files are not accessible from the nodes of the Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: wondering why we can't directly use "logstash" to read the files "/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/application.log" ... etc.

Is that inefficient, one less headache of using filebeat.